# Battlestar Galactica relationship regulations

Tags: battlestar-galactica

In Battlestar Galactica we see plenty of relationship between military themselves (all kind of ranks) and military-civilians in "time of war":

Examples:

Military-military:

- *Helo*-*Athena*
- *Starbuck*-*Apollo*
- *Starbuck*-Sam (pilot)
- *Apollo*-Dualla

Military-Civilian:

- Dualla-Billy
- *Starbuck*-Sam (before being a pilot)
- Adama-Roslin

...and no one bats an eye.

Nevertheless, one of the big plot points of season 1 is the *"secret forbidden relationship"* between *Boomer* and Chief Tyrol. **Why is the relationship between Tyrol and *Boomer* not allowed?** Is it because Tyrol is a "Non-commisioned officer"? It's the only difference I can find between him and the rest of the crew.

Relevant quote by Adama, in the argument leading up to Tyrol-Boomer's break up:

> **Adama:** *[to Tyrol, after Socinus has been incarcerated]* (...) You’ll pay a different price.
>   You’ll have to walk out on that hangar every day knowing that one of
>   your men is in the brig because you couldn’t keep your fly zipped. **You
>   are the most experienced non-commissioned officer we have left.** You
>   keep my planes flying. I need my planes to fly.

Comment: Is it because mechanics are a special race that should only breed with themselves, AKA Cally? (Although not really...)

Comment: It's been a while, but I thought the Adama-Roslin one at least caused some problems. People didn't like the military chief being so cosy with the government one.

Comment: @JeremyFrench true, Zarek used that argument, but my point is that it was not *legally* forbidden.

Comment: Is it _"because frak Tyrol"_?

Comment: For future reference, here's a link to the [United States Uniform Code of Military Justice.](http://www.ucmj.us/)

Comment: @JoeL.It would be more useful a link to the appropiate section. Actually a citation from that section could be an answer (since we could assume that Galactica borrows from (or is inspired by) the UCMJ :)

Comment: Starbuck, not Starbucks.  Starbucks makes coffee, Starbuck is a Viper pilot.

Comment: @JRE Woops, I thought they were the same :P Editing!

Answer (score 12):

found this snippet on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Number_Eight_(Battlestar_Galactica)):

> Boomer and Galen Tyrol are romantically involved, although their relationship is against military protocol (she is an officer, he's enlisted)

[Fraternization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fraternization#Within_militaries) between officers and enlisted people is discouraged or prohibited in real world military organizations, the reasons for this, such as ability to make tactical decisions (which could risk the lives of enlisted people) or uphold the chain of command, hold for the navy in Galactica too.

Also, it is worth remembering that protocols change once your civilization is destroyed and you are fighting for survival on a daily basis. There was also the long term need to repopulate.

> Adama: [sees Billy flirting with Dualla] They'd better start having babies.
>
> Saul Tigh: Is that an order?
>
> Adama: It may be before too long.

Comment: Are all pilots "officers"? Because if not, Starbucks-Sam would be in the same situation. There's no mention of a change in relationship regulations betweetn season 1 (Tyler-Boomer) and 3 (Sam-Starbuck), both being "after the apocalypse".

Comment: Hmm, looking into yes. battlestar wiki has him as an Ensign, which is apparently still an Officer rank. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ensign_(rank)

Comment: So basically if you are an officer it's ok to frak both other officers or civilians, but no those *enlisted peasants*, is that it?

Comment: Oh you can frack them, just don't go getting romantically involved. ;)

Comment: I assumed things were relaxed after the "we need to start having babies speech..."

Comment: I thought I remembered something about that. It's not an uncommon trope in post apocalyptic scenarios so I couldn't be sure it was in galactica.

Comment: They mention the *"we need to start having babies"* in the miniseries, if I'm not mistaken, which is before season 1, yet still they have "abortion dilemmas" well into season 2 (S02E17). If there was a relaxation of the military law, it was not mentioned, but there's not any other case of enlisted-officer relationship I can think of, anyways, so I guess we'll never know...